# Make vertical ScrollViewer invisible

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, controls, styles

I have a ScrollViewer control in my window and I would like to hide it when the user cannot scroll down the page. Just like with the horizontal scroll viewer. here is an example:

so here both scrollers are visible because scrolling is enabled:
[image]

if I collapse some of the columns of my listview note how eventually the horizontal scroller disappears:
[image]

Now note what happens with the vertical scroller:

[image]

so far its visible and that's ok because not all the content fits in the page. But let me maximize the page and co-lapse all the group boxes so that all the content fits in the page:

[image]

Why is it visible if it is not possible to scroll? I set all the group boxes height = 0 except the last one and the vertical scroller still shoes up? The horizontal scroller disappeared when it was not possible to scroll any more. Why does the vertical scroller does not behave the same way?

What can I do to make it invisible when it is not possible to scroll?

Comment: Are you setting the scrollbar to auto visibility?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure that your Scrollviewer's VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

Comment: One down side to this is if you have nested scrollbars, once the mouse enters the area of the nested and hidden view, it will stop scrolling with the mouse wheel.