# How to hid scrollbar in navigationview

Tags: xaml, uwp

i'm using navigationview and want to hide scrollbar.
but ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" is useless.
[Operation results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gChb.jpg)

```
 <NavigationView x:Name="ConrtolList"
                        IsSettingsVisible="False"
                        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                        IsBackEnabled="True"
                        AlwaysShowHeader="True"
                        PaneTitle="后台管理"
                        PaneDisplayMode="Left"
                        ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="500"
                        SelectionFollowsFocus="Disabled"
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        Loaded="nvSample_Loaded"
                        SelectionChanged="ConrtolList_SelectionChanged"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                       >
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="主页" Tag="Home" x:Name="SamplePage1Item">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon  Symbol="home"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="批发商管理"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="批发商账户" Tag="MerchantsAccount" x:Name="MerchantsAccount">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="People" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="商品审核" Tag="CommodityJustice" x:Name="CommodityJustice" SelectsOnInvoked="True">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="BrowsePhotos" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="违禁商户" Tag="MerchantsBan" x:Name="MerchantsBan">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Dislike" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="商户申诉" Tag="MerchantsAppel" x:Name="MerchantsAppel">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Help" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="零售商管理"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="零售商账户" Tag="DealerAccount" x:Name="DealerAccount">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="People" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="违禁零售商" Tag="DealerBan" x:Name="DealerBan">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Dislike" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="零售商申诉" Tag="DealerAppel" x:Name="DealerAppel">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Help" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="商品管理"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="商品一览" Tag="CommodityCheck" x:Name="CommodityCheck">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Paste" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="商品修改" Tag="CommodityUpdate" x:Name="CommodityUpdate">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="违禁商品" Tag="CommodityBan" x:Name="CommodityBan">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Dislike" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="订单管理"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="订单一览" Tag="BullCheck" x:Name="BullCheck">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Page2" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <StackPanel x:Name="FooterStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible">
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="信息下载" Icon="Download" AutomationProperties.Name="download" />
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="信息导入" Icon="Add" AutomationProperties.Name="favorite" />
                </StackPanel>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" />
        </NavigationView>
```

So how to hide the scroll bar pointed by the arrow.
I add `<NavigationView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">` to hidding scrollbar,but it useless.
The scrollbar still visible.
I didn't find this solution in the official documents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make vertical ScrollViewer invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541734/make-vertical-scrollviewer-invisible)

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that you are using now? Where is the ScrollBar? It will be better if you could share the screenshot about the behavior that you are getting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't clarify my question and didn't reply to you in time.

I have revised the problem.  @Roy Li - MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to hid scrollbar in navigationview

You need to create a default style of `NavigationView`. Then find the `NavigationViewList` which is named as **MenuItemsHost**. Set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property of the `NavigationViewList` to **Hidden**.

Like this:

```
            <NavigationViewList x:Name="MenuItemsHost"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplate}" 
                            ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyle}"
                            ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemTemplateSelector}"
                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                            ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding MenuItemContainerStyleSelector}" 
                            Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="6" SelectionMode="Single" 
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            SingleSelectionFollowsFocus="{Binding TemplateSettings.SingleSelectionFollowsFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
```

To create a default style of the `NavigationView`, please open the **Document Outline** window in Visual Studio. Then find the `NavigationView` control, right-click on it, choose **Edit Template->Edit a Copy**. The Visual Studio will automatically generate a default style of the `NavigationView`.